# scrollbars and isScrollContainer attributes do not activate scrolling for linear layout

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout

I want to add a scrolling to my main layout(linear layout)

if I add the `scrollbars` and `isScrollContainer` attributes in the linear layout, the scrolling does not work. any explanation why these attributes do not activate scrolling

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:isScrollContainer="true">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Make your LinearLayout Scrollable put it in ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
...
...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

isScrollContainer="true"
```

This property is used when your softkey in android pops up and still you want your view to scroll.